# Google linechart visualization chart disappears when updating it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I want to be able to update the line chart of google visualizations. My code was inspired by [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200917/trying-to-update-a-google-visualization-using-jquery).

Here is my code in question:

http://jsfiddle.net/YCqyG/5/

You'll see that when you click the button titled "click", the chart suddenly disappears.

---

**UPDATE:**
When I comment out this line, it appears to be working:

```
// this.element.html('');
```

And it does not appear to work for the line chart. Any idea why it won't work for the line chart?

Comment: Why do you not have an error function on your AJAX get? If I was a betting person..

Comment: I just updated my fiddle anbd passed it an object literal, removed all ajax call, and the error still occurs. Click the "click" button on the fiddle and you will see the error occur. thanks for responses.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a few issues around the usage of jQuery selectors in your code; it's somewhat confusing around the sections where you're calling `$(element)` and `$(element)[0]` etc. In general I'd avoid jQuery here, the refresh works by replacing both of:

- `add('LineChart', '#mileage')` with `add('LineChart', 'mileage')`
- `$(element)[0]` with `document.getElementById(element)`

Some general advice here:

- You don't need to clear out the div before re-rendering a chart (i.e.: No need to call `this.element.html('')`, simple passing in a new data table and re-calling `.draw(newDataTable, opts)` is fine. Whilst potentially beyond the needs of this post, the new [gviz animation functionality](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/animation.html) is a good example of this (you just call redraw with updated data, and the graph animates the change).
- Obviously I'm unaware of the full need of your implementation, but I feel like your code may be slightly more involved than you need. Depending on how you get can data sent from your server, you can pretty easily reload a chart. I've given some details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312744/refresh-google-visualization-on-the-fly/8324093#8324093), but in brief it looks like this:

  ```
  function drawMyChart(dataTable) {
      // convert your dataTable to the right format
      // options here include loading from arrays, json representations of your datatable
      // or something more manual perhaps
      var opts = {height:50, width:50};
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('vis'));
      chart.draw(dataTable, opts);
  }

  function makeAjaxCall() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/path/to/data/json',
          sucess: drawMyChart(a),
          dataType: 'json' // this is important, have it interpreted as json
      });
  }
  // html somewhere
  <div id='vis'></div>
  <input type='button' onclick='makeAjaxCall()'>Go</input>
  ```

Hope that helps.